# How Can I Force Google Maps to Keep the Map Viewport as it is?

Tags: google-maps

When searching for some terms (say, "restaurant", "toy store", "post office", etc.) in Google Maps, Google Maps tends to automatically change the zoom level and sometimes also shift the map so that a reasonable number of results included in the viewport.

This is very confusing, especially if the jump is to a totally other location, or when I had already found a certain street or square and just want to find the nearest stores of a kind, if any, and then have to find the street or square again because the zoom level changed.

**Ideally, the map viewport should stay exactly as it is, even if that means no results are found. How can I force Google Maps to behave like that?**

(I am only looking for solutions that do not require me to log in to Google, as I often do quick searches on maps and thus do not want to log in every time (let alone remain logged in all the time).)